# MLKit iOS: Undefined symbols for architecture armv7

Tags: ios, objective-c, architecture, armv7, firebase-mlkit

I have been trying to integrate `MLKit` into `CardIO` using `cocoapod`. I fixed all the warnings by `cocoapod` and `CardIO` was built successfully. However, when I link `CardIO` to my app and build, this error comes out. I searched all over the internet and tried different kind of approaches suggested by people but still to no avail. Is there any step or setting I might have missed during integration/linking?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRVisionImage", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in libCardIO.a(CardIOView.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRVision", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in libCardIO.a(CardIOView.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue right now!


Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRVisionImage", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ScanViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRVision", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ScanViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: @ltzdsp did you able to fix it? I'm still stucking here

Comment: yeah i fixed in my project. 

I added $(inherited) in Other Linker flags, Header search paths, Framework search Paths, Library search Paths in "Target -> Build Settings" resolved the issue! Add that flag, delete derived data and run pod install. Open your workspace file.

Answer (score 0):

I added `$(inherited)` in Other Linker flags, Header search paths, Framework search Paths, Library search Paths in "Target -> Build Settings" resolved the issue! Happy Coding!